# Select fields with Knockout.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, select, knockout.js, datepicker

When I include the knockout.js library, all of my select fields disappear.  Is there a way for select fields to ignore knockout.js?

It affects not only my drop downs, but also date picker...i.e. I have the following code:

```
    <center>
      <%= f.text_field :firstdate, :style=>"width:150px;" %> 
      - 
      <%= f.text_field :seconddate, :style=>"width:150px;" %>
      <script>
      $(function() {
            $( "#post_firstdate" ).datepicker({
                  changeMonth: true,
                  changeYear: true,
                  yearRange: "-112:+5"
            });
            $( "#post_seconddate" ).datepicker({
                  changeMonth: true,
                  changeYear: true,
                  yearRange: "-112:+5"
            });
      });
      </script>
    </center>
```

While I can select dates in data picker, typically the Month and Year fields are drop downs as well.  Now they disappear.

Are there any suggestions on how to have certain fields ignore knockout?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found the answer...just remove this from dropout.css  This way only fields you want dropkick to change will be effected.

```
.dk_fouc select {
  position: relative;
  top: -99999em;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```